# Integrating MvcMiniProfiler.RavenDB with ServiceStack.MiniProfiler

Tags: ravendb, servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

I have tried to follow the instruction mentioned on the [ServiceStack.MiniProfiler page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling), on the [MvcMiniProflier.RavenDB page](http://csainty.github.com/MvcMiniProfiler.RavenDb/)  and on the [MiniProfiler page](http://miniprofiler.com/) but I cannot get the profiling data for RavenDB to be displayed in the ServiceStack.MiniProfiler rendered output.
The ServiceStack.MiniProfiler rendered output gets displayed correctly when I call my web service method in the browser.

Can this be done through configuration or does it need an additional component?

Comment: Not sure about ServiceStack's profiler, but there's a contrib project for Raven with MiniProfiler [in the repository here](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb.contrib).  Look under `src/Raven.Client.Contrib.Profiling`